# How to guarantee constraint between SQL rows?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, concurrent-programming

We are developing online schedule application. One schedule can be edited simultaneously by several users. There is one very important business constraint. There must be only three events in one day.

Technically speaking and simplifying, there is a table in database with columns: | id | event | date |. Application runs in transaction "select... count... where..." and if result is less than 3, it inserts new event.

Wich approaches can be used to guarantee that two threads will not create four events in one day? This is a classical check-and-write problem. And we wonder how it can be solved on database level?

Using transactions doesn`t guarantee that in the second transaction another thread will not do the same: checks that number of events is less than 3 and makes insert. Locking the whole table is not acceptable because it will reduce response time, concurrency, etc.

Application is developed in Java using Spring, Hibernate, MySQL.

Thanks in advance for any pieces of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For blocking process you should use Select ... FOR UPDATE statement. But this one works only in innodb.

Example:

```
//java logic
try {
    //mysql logic
    start transaction;
    select * from where 'some condition' FOR UPDATE
    INSERT INTO TABLE ....    
    commit;
//java logic
catch (Exception e) {
    rollback;
}
```

See more info about specific row locking http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Thanks. We are using InnoDB. So this solution can be appropriate for us. But do you think this SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is in fact equal to locking the whole table, like LOCK TABLE?

Comment: No, it will lock only specific rows which you select. So you can test this one in the following way: run 2 mysql console, start transaction and run select in these ones, play with different condition. it will be more clear how it works.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. We will definitely try this approach.

Comment: This probably (I don't know innodb) won't work when there are no rows which match your where clause. If two users both try to insert 2 rows at the same time then you will end up with 4 rows.

Comment: @user430904 I wrote about innodb. Could you give an example?

Comment: Say user 1 & user 2 both want to insert 2 events for tomorrow's date, and that there are no rows for tomorrows's date already in the table.

Comment: Doing 'select * from event where date = tomorrow' will return no rows - so there is nothing to lock. user 1 will issue that select, locking no rows. If user 2 then runs the query, before user 1 commits, then they won't be blocked, but will return no rows.  Both users will then insert 2 rows.

Comment: In this case we should have unique constraint for preventing duplication.

Comment: @AndrejL let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2812/discussion-between-user430904-and-andrej-l)

Comment: Unfortunately, UNIQUE and other database constraints don`t help us. Actual business logic is more complicated than it was described in question. For example, there is one special type. And if day has event of this type, there can`t be any other events. So what we need to do is: SELECT ... WHERE date, perform check of business constraints, INSERT. Is it possible to synchronize work of several threads using only database mechanisms without locking the whole table?

Comment: Have you checked my main idea about FOR UPDATE?

Comment: Yes, in general it works. But it is necessary to implement requests retries, because one of two competitive requests gets deadlock exception. Besides, we a not sure yet whether it works correctly in case described by user430904. Probably, we will try approach described by Aaron Sheffey. But he suggested not database level solution.

Answer (score 0):

With your data model you could use a check constraint to count the number of rows. AFAIK MySQL doesn't natively support this type of constraint, but it looks like it's possible to [emulate them with a trigger](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints)

Alternatively you could consider a different data model with a `days` table and an `events` table. You could use [optimistic locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic) of `days` to ensure that a second transaction didn't have an out of date understanding of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going through Spring, and since there is a concurrency issue, try synchronizing execution at the Java layer, rather than at the DB layer.  We've had similar issues when trying to use a DB to maintain concurrency.

Perhaps you could make the execution block in Java `synchronized` so that it forces execution to block; inside the synchronized method, check that all of your business logic returns true.  if true, continue with normal execution.  If false, abort with an exception.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. We bear in mind synchronization on application level (Java level). And we will use it, if we don`t find database level solution.